# How to i add a background music to a video in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ffmpeg

How do I add background music to a video in React Native? using ffmpeg-kit? https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/react-native

I have a video in my project root folder, But the audio I want to add is a remote URL stored in the cloud music link is https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4

Can anyone give me a basic example to do this in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

you can insert a muted video and simultaneously play audio in a React Native app using different libraries. react-native-video is one of the most commonly used libraries for video playback in React Native. However, the react-native-video library itself does not support audio playback. To achieve the desired effect, you can combine react-native-video with the react-native-sound library.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Set the video to mute
    Sound.setCategory('Playback'); // Enable background audio
    const audio = new Sound('path-to-your-audio.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, error => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Error playing audio:', error);
        return;
      }
      // Play the audio
      audio.play();
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Video
        source={require('path-to-your-video.mp4')}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        muted // Set the video to mute
        resizeMode="cover"
        repeat
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Be sure to replace 'path-to-your-video.mp4' and 'path-to-your-audio.mp3' with the correct paths to your video and audio files.

**Important notes**:

Ensure that the audio and video you're using have formats supported by their respective libraries.
Sound.setCategory('Playback') is used to enable background audio on iOS.
This example is simplified, and you might want to add more robust playback controls and error handling.
Please note that the user experience and the behavior of the app in the background might vary based on device configurations and operating system restrictions.

Comment: I'm using React Native for mobile

Comment: My bad sorry, edited the answer.

Comment: @DariaS I'm already using it but my question is really how to merge a audio to a video in react native...

Comment: @James was not properly clear, but i edited again :)

Comment: But i dont mean that i mean how to combine audio to a video in react native ?

Comment: That's what the code do, It combine audio and video to a "virtual" unique "track", that's not what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ffmpeg-kit-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-kit-react-native?activeTab=readme) to add audio as background in your video

sample code :

```html
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { executeFFmpeg } from 'ffmpeg-kit-react-native';

const AddBackgroundMusicScreen = () => {
  const addBackgroundMusic = async () => {
    const videoPath = 'path_to_input_video.mp4';
    const audioPath = 'path_to_input_audio.mp3';
    const outputPath = 'path_to_output_video.mp4';

    const command = `-i ${videoPath} -i ${audioPath} -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental ${outputPath}`;

    try {
      await executeFFmpeg(command);
      console.log('Background music added successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error adding background music:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Add Background Music" onPress={addBackgroundMusic} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default AddBackgroundMusicScreen;
```

In the FFmpeg command:

-i ${videoPath} specifies the input video file.

-i ${audioPath} specifies the input audio file.

-c:v copy copies the video stream without re-encoding.

-c:a aac -strict experimental encodes the audio stream to AAC format.

${outputPath} specifies the output video file.

Comment: How do i get outputPath?

Comment: if you are using react-native-fs output path can be RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath +'/NewVideoWIthBackgoundMusic.mp4'

Comment: I'm having trouble installing ffmpeg-kit-react-native for andriod and ios, if possible do you have any GitHub repo that uses new version of react native and do this thing? it would be helpful

Comment: i dont have a public repo to share ... what issue you are having while installing this package ? i just followed the documentation https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/react-native

Comment: i did that but got errors one by one

Comment: can you share your repo i ll try to look into that